# VMWare API for vStorage

Tags: api, vmware

I was wondering where I can download the vStorage APIs?

Does anybody know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to join the TSA Network for VMWare.
2. You need to go to VmWare training, then you can get the API.